# symfony2 form validation formbuilder and custom form type

Tags: validation, symfony

i'm creating a form with ancustom form type.

This is my mainform:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('area', new AreaSelectType($this->em, true, true, $this->organizercountry), array('selectedArea'  => null,'label' => 'City'));        
    $builder->add('location', new LocationAutocompleteType('#steptwo_location_autocomplete', '#steptwo_location_hidden', '#steptwo_area_pkid'));                        
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{

    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(            
        'area' => new NotNull(array('message' => 'nicht leer')),            
        'location' => new NotNull(array('message' => 'nicht leer'))            
    ));

    return array('validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint);                
}
```

This is the LocationAutocompleteType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->setAttribute('source', $options['source']);                        
    $builder->add('autocomplete', 'text', array('label' => false, 'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off')));
    $builder->add('hidden', 'hidden', array('label' => false, 'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off')));        
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {

    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(            
        'hidden' => new NotNull(array('message' => 'nicht leer')),                        
    ));

    return array('validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint, 'source' => 'organizer.ajax.location');                                
}
```

Evertything i do, the custom Formtype is not validated.
What must i do to validate the form type correctly and get the Error via the Location Attribute in the parent Form ?

Answer (score 2):

In `getDefaultOptions` method of main form you have to add `'cascade_validation' => true` to to returned array to enable validation on child forms. It is a recent change that hasn't been updated in documentation yet.